# Capybara: How to hit the first button in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Here is the html source code for 2 `Save` buttons in `Rails 4` spec. The program should click the first `Save`:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/view_handler?index=0">
  <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.Back">Back</span>
 </a>
 <input class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary" name="commit" value="Save" type="submit">
 <input class="btn btn-default btn btn-primary" name="commit" value="Save & New" and_new="true" type="submit">
</div>`
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
first('input.btn.btn-default').click_button 'Save'
```

The error returned is:

> Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>              Unable to find button "Save"

What's the right way to click button `Save` in spec?

Comment: doesn't `first('input.btn.btn-default').click` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons have different text value one is 'Save' and the other 'Save & New'

```
within '.btn-toolbar' do
  click_button 'Save'
end
```

Should work for your case.

Comment: It works and thanks.  Before posting, I tried `within 'input.btn.btn-default' do click_button('Save', match: :first) end` and it did not work. Any explaination why yours working?

Comment: @user938363 I think it is because that what you have written mean "click button 'Save' inside `input.btn.btn-default` button". As far as there is no button inside the button, it didn't work.